# How to replace lines that contains integers by using sed

Tags: linux, file, sed

I have a file that contains two fields. The first field may or may not contain an Integer. If it contains an integer and a dot follows the integer  I would like to manipulate part of second field. So As an example:

```
301.    301+Num+Ord          # Change this one 301+Num+Card
100.    100+Num+Ord          # Change this one 100+Num+Card 
3'üncü  3+Num+Ord            # DONOT CHANGE THIS ONE
48.7    48.7+Num+Real        # DONOT CHANGE THIS ONE EITHER . is not at the end
24      24+Num+Card          # DONOT CHANGE THIS ONE No dot
4.      4+Num+Ord          #  Change this one 4+Num+Card
.        .+Punct              # DONOT CHANGE THIS ONE
```

I couldn't make it since I have very limited knowledge in regex. I would be very appreciate if you can help me. thanks

Comment: [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input and separate expected output. See [ask].

Comment: to avoid confusion you should post it separately as input file and expected output.... and you should add whatever you tried to question so as to not portray as asking entire code for free.. after all you are asking question because you tried something but got stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following awk command and let me know if this helps you.
Since you haven't told us which is the next text which you want on place of 2nd column in case it needs to be changed I am simply taking a test string.

```
awk '($1 ~ /[0-9]+\.$/){sub("Ord","Card",$2)} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file
```

**Explanation:** `awk` has by default delimiter as space so `$1` represents column 1 here. So I am checking here by doing `$1 ~ /[0-9]+\./$` here if a 1st column is having digits in it followed by a DOT at last of column(`\.` means I am using escape sequence to remove DOT's special meaning here), if yes then I am substitute `ord` with `card` in 2nd field by using `sub`(substitute) utility of `awk` here. Then `1` means I am making condition TRUE here and not mentioning and action here so by default action print will happen.

Comment: Actually I put it as comment .
The parts starting with # are my comments they are not part of file . As you can see, at each time I change a line,I replace Ord with Card and keep the rest same

Comment: Actually there is a small problem.  Before manipulating, fields are seperated by tab but when it is edited I guess they're now seperated with spaces right ? How could I change it too ? @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @zwlayer, kindly see my edit now you could add OFS="\t" before Input_file and it should be TAB delimited then, let me know if you have any further queries on same.

Comment: the latest edition gives me error: 
`awk: cmd. line:1: ($1 ~ /[0-9]+\./$){sub("Ord","Card",$2)} 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: ($1 ~ /[0-9]+\./$){sub("Ord","Card",$2)} 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: ($1 ~ /[0-9]+\./$){sub("Ord","Card",$2)} 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                        ^ syntax error
`

Comment: @zwlayer, apologies there was a typo, fixed it now, it should fly now.

Comment: Exactly as you said Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

OP ask for sed so

```
sed -E '/^[0-9]+\.[[:space:]]/!b;s/(^.*[[:space:]]+)([^[:space:]]*$)/\1Change this one/' infile
```